# Display a standard grid for a external list connected through BCS

Tags: list, 2016, bcs, external-list, gridview

**Environment**

- Sharepoint 2016.
- Visual Studio 2017.
- Sharepoint Add-In in a hosted environment.

**Requirements**

Display an external list connected through BCS in a standard grid view with possibility of read, add, edit and delete records.

**Example**

An example of a standard grid view is below.

[image]

**What have been done**

- I've created an add-in.
- Added an external content type.
  [image]
- Learned how to get the list elements with javascript's API.
- Found the SPGridView.

**The problem**

Find a way how to put this list in a standard grid view to read, add, edit and delete elements with a standard Sharepoint's UX.

Could you describe how to put an external list connected through BCS to a standard Sharepoint's grid?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use an add-in. You should use Sharepoint's designer and create external type and external list. Found answer here - http://www.fabiangwilliams.com/2013/10/14/blog-update-on-sharepoint-bcs-with-full-crud-part-1-of-3/#comment-95714.